# I spilled candle wax on the video card in my computer, should I be concerned?

Tags: computers

I have just accidentally spilled lavender scented candle wax onto my video card. This is a RX480, the kind with holes that expose parts of the circuitry. the way the candle wax fell, it got onto that side with the circuitry partially exposed and so now there are little drops of wax in there. I have read that candle wax vapor is highly flammable, but there is only a little bit of wax on there.

Would I be better off buying a new video card? It is still in my computer and I am currently using it, it still functions fine.

Comment: what is preventing you from cleaning out the wax?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how could this happen at all? :-D

Comment: If you smell lavender, close a few tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and clean off the excess wax carefully with something absorbent (without lint) like a piece of kitchen towel. The wax may melt and run if the PC is on due to the card heating up. This of course might make it easier to remove.

The wax is not likely to cause a problem with your card. The PC may smell like a giant "Airwick Freshmatic" for a while though.